# Don't know how to access array data inside dictionary [: []], Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am stuck with this guy [ : []]. As you can see, currently inside function I am using [0] to access value, but with this type of solution I can only access first element of array. How can I access all values? I tried with for in loop, but couldn't solve it...

Thanks in advance!

```
func tripServices(tripId: String) {
    networkManager.getBookedTripsDetails(endpoint: "/v1/bookings/\(tripId)", tripId: tripId) { [unowned self] (safeTripsDetails) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bookedTripDetails = self.createScreenData(from: safeTripsDetails!, singleTrip: self.singleTrip!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func createScreenData(from data: [String: [BookingService]], singleTrip: BookedTripsForView) -> [DetailsAboutServiceForView] {
    
    return data.map{ ( data) -> DetailsAboutServiceForView in
        return DetailsAboutServiceForView(id: singleTrip.id,
                                          destination: data.value[0].destination,
                                          tripStatus: data.value[0].status,
                                          tripStartTime: data.value[0].startDate,
                                          serviceName: data.value[0].serviceName,
                                          serviceId: data.value[0].serviceId)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that error was made by Asol (and those who approved the edit)

Comment: What is your desired output? You want an array of `DetailsAboutServiceForView` that combines `DetailsAboutServiceForView` objects for each of the arrays in your dictionary?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't cause any errors since I **only** suggested to add additional source code :)

Comment: @Asol No I said you _made_ an error but I guess mistake would have been a better word than error. Anyway, you should not add comments like you did in the question when editing it. Comments are posted here, in the comments section.

Comment: @Asol, editing is to correct typos/clarfiy the OP's (original poster's) question. You should not add comments into the OPs question, or change the nature of the post. If you have a comment, use the comments section, as Joakim suggests.

Comment: @DuncanC  OK! Will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: These things compose. Within `data.map`, the paramater `data` (Arg, that's a terrible name! Not only does it shadow an existing variable with a totally different type, but it's totally non descriptive. Technically, there is nothing in a program that can't be called "data"!). Each value in your dict is an array, and in the same way you can `map` over a dict to do something with each key value pair, you can `map` over the value (the array) to do something with each array element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dictionary of arrays, and you want your output to be a single array containing all of the arrays combined into one array of a different type, there are various ways you could do that.

Rather than trying to work out your data types, I banged out an example using simple structs:

```
//Source struct
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

//Output struct
struct Employee {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let salary: Int?
}

let dictOfArrays = ["key1": [Person(name: "Bob", age: 36),
                             Person(name: "Felecia", age: 27),
                             Person(name: "Armin", age: 19)],
                    
                    "key2": [Person(name: "Janet", age: 57),
                             Person(name: "John", age: 12),
                             Person(name: "Karen", age: 43)]
]

//Create an empty array for the output
var output = [Employee]()

//Loop through the dictionaries
dictOfArrays.forEach { (_, values) in
    values.forEach { person in
        //Only those who are >=18 can be employees
        if person.age >= 18 {
            output.append( Employee(name: person.name, age: person.age, salary: nil))
        }
    }
}

//Logs the resulting array of Employee structs.
output.forEach { print($0) }
```

### Edit:

As pointed out by Alexander in his comment, you can do the above in one statement without creating an array var and appending to it using a combination of flatmap, filter, and map:

```
let output = dictOfArrays.flatMap { (_, values) in
    values.filter { $0.age >= 18 }
    .map { person in
        Employee(name: person.name, age: person.age, salary: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this without a mutable array and manual appending: ```let output2 = dictOfArrays.flatMap { (_, values) in
    values.filter { $0.age >= 18 }.map { person in
        Employee(name: person.name, age: person.age, salary: nil)
    }
}``` ah the formatting got messed, but you got the idea